# Есть ли возможность дать доступ к Internet узлу в VPN при подключении к нему по ssh

Tags: администрирование, vpn

У моего клиента есть закрытая сеть `VPN` с сотней машин под `Ubuntu`. У меня есть доступ по `ssh`. Я должен по мере необходимости обновлять компоненты и ПО на них. Есть ли возможность при подключении к машине дать ей временную возможность выхода в Internet изнутри `VPN` (например через мое подключение), чтобы была возможность обновиться поставить доп ПО и т.д. Возможно у меня неправильный подход, но просить каждый раз администратора сети дать временный доступ не выход и, как я понял, весьма их утомляет. Буду признателен если подскажете в какую сторону копать.

Comment: А система обновления ПО умеет работать через socks прокси ? ssh может пробрасывать трафик через socks (google: "ssh socks"). Если обновление через него работать не готово, надо сделать этот сокс прозрачным (google: "linux transparent socks"). ну и возможно настроить свою машину что бы она весь пришедний трафик в интернет отправляла (если не сделает это по умолчанию)